# Compilation fails after adding classes using Room - ANDROID

Tags: android, sqlite, data-binding, android-room

I added Room to my Gradle and everything compiled OK,
but when I try to add classes that use Room DataBase it falls:
my classes for Room:

**UserUsageDoa**

```
package com.meissa.model.UserUsage;

import android.arch.persistence.room.Dao;

@Dao
public interface UserUsageDao {
}
```

**UserUsageDB:**

```
package com.meissa.model.UserUsage;

import android.arch.persistence.room.Database;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Room;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase;
import android.content.Context;

@Database(entities = Meter.class, version = 1)
public abstract class UserUsageDB extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserUsageDao userUsageDao();
    private static volatile UserUsageDB userUsageDBInstance;//singleton

        static UserUsageDB getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (userUsageDBInstance == null) {
            synchronized (UserUsageDB.class) {
                if (userUsageDBInstance == null) {
                    userUsageDBInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            UserUsageDB.class, "user_usage_database")
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return userUsageDBInstance;
    }
}
```

**Meter**

```
package com.meissa.model.UserUsage;

import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import com.meissa.model.Configuration.ConfigManager;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity(tableName = "meters")
public class Meter implements Serializable {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    int mID;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    String mMeterName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "pb_version")
    String mMeterPBVersion;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "am_version")
    String mMeterAMVersion;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "calibration_date")
    Date mCalibrationDate;

    public Meter(int mID, @NonNull String mMeterName) {
        this.mID = mID;
        this.mMeterName = mMeterName;
        mMeterPBVersion = "0";
        mMeterAMVersion = "0";
        mCalibrationDate =new Date();
    }

}
```

and then I get the compilation errors :

error: package com.meissa.databinding does not exist
import com.meissa.databinding.FragmentLogSettingsBinding;
 error: cannot find symbol
import com.meissa.BR;
                          ^
  symbol:   class BR

I get the same above errors on all the Data Binding I have in my project, 
Room dosn't go with Data binding?
can you help?

Comment: Open `Build Output` -> `Toggle View` from Android Studio and build project again, you will see the actual error of your code, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgGvY.png

Comment: I opened the output, nothing there that tells me what the problem is, as you see I attached what is written there

Comment: Your attached error does not tell what goes wrong in your code. Make sure that `Toggle View` is on, otherwise the actual errors are not shown. Refer to this thread for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582151/android-gradle-compilationfailedexception-after-android-studio-update

Comment: @theshyelf what I added there is from the toggle view, I'll attach a pic

Comment: No, it is not, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i7J6.gif

Comment: I wish they have a name for that button :D

Comment: @theshyelf when I click on this button I get errors on all the Data Binding I have in my project, Room can't go together with Data binding??

Comment: Please update your question with those errors, thanks

Comment: @theshyelf I updated my question with the errors I'm getting, but it is not the Data binding it is the Room, without Room data binding works grate in my project

Comment: @batsheva did you find the solution?

Comment: @yes, I upgraded all my project to API28, when a project is not compiling, the data binding sends errors, even though there are no errors over there